# How to clear console without Flikerring in C/C++

Tags: c

So I am making a snake game in C but the problem is that it causes a lot of flickering and it also slow downs the game, So I heard that double buffering can solve this but I don't know how to implement that and other ways will also be appreciated. For now I have just reposition the cursor to 0 and disable the visibility of cursor.

Comment: Online compilers are really not suited for interactive programs. Maybe you can download a real compiler to your computer and try with [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Another option is buying a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) where you can do whatever you want even (awkwardly) from a mobile phone.

Answer (score 4):

The way games typically prevent this "flickering" is due to double buffering. As the current view is being rendered, the back view is performing updates. When the two views swap, the back view clears and performs the updates for the next frame while the current view is being rendered from the previous frame. In Console, you don't have this luxury and when I was writing my snake game in terminal I solved it by not redrawing the entire console every "frame". Rather, I simply drew an empty space over the last tail position and kept the rest of the frame the same. Similar with the snake going over the food, just draw over it with an empty space.

I believe the function I had written was something like this.

```
void clearlastposition(GameState* state){
 _COORD last;
 last.X = state->snake.back().partposition.x;
 last.Y = state->snake.back().partposition.y;
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),last);
 printf(" ");
}
```

In my design, the snake body was a vector of snake parts. Where each part contained an x and y position. And the GameState just held an instance to the snake body.
This was done on Windows.

Comment: Ok, the only way was that I shifted to the real Windows compiler. Then I used some predefined functions and Macros of Winapi 

Here's my  NON-FLICKERING GAME "https://github.com/Lovish-Garg/Projects/blob/master/C/Game/Non-GUI/Snake/SnakeGame.c"

Comment: I guess that works. It's just more unnecessary writing/drawing. You're just setting the cursor position to 0 every frame then redrawing over it. I wouldn't say that's a better solution. Because you aren't double buffering you should only redraw what needs to be redrawn and leave anything that's untouched previous frame.

Comment: Yeah you're right Nina, but as I wanted a simple solution so I just position the cursor to 0 and it doesnot cause any flickering.